# What's the difference between opposite and in front of?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases, phrase-choice

What's the difference between **opposite** and **in front of**?

> the bank is **opposite** the mall
>   the bank is **in front of** the mall

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you? What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: @Kanu If you are reading these comments, please let us know. When someone asks what your English language dictionary tells you about a word, it is because we can write a better answer for you if we know what _you_ know. Sometimes dictionary definitions are hard for a new learner to read, and sometimes a dictionary definition isn't very clear, even to an English speaker! We can help you with that.

Comment: @ P.E Dant Yes, thank you. I asked cause in a textbook exercise there's a picture with a mall on the left, a street, a bench on the sidewalk (on the right side of the picture) and a bank (also on the right). I hope you can visualize that. It's MALL - STREET - SIDEWALK/BENCH - BANK. The answer it brings is the mall is opposite the bank and the bench is in front of the bank, but the only difference between the mall and a the bench is a few meters, it's the same position...

Comment: So, it looked like I could say the bench in opposite the bank and the mall is in front of the bank. The dictionary says opposite is facing/across from. In front of is before or ahead like in a classroom or line. Anyway, the bench and the mall are facing the bank

Comment: @Kanu Thanks for the going to the effort; upvoted. I think Lijero's answer is more or less correct intuitively, but note that even the OED doesn't mention the "something in between" factor. I think that either term could be used with or without something in between, largely dependent on what that thing is. (Is a big patch of grass a thing or nothing?) But for distinguishing between them, I think it's exactly right. The street divides the mall from the bank, but not the bench from the bank.

Comment: For more fun, why is the moon in front of the sun during an eclipse but two boxers in a ring are opposite each other? Anyhow, it works for the street example. Or does it? If there's a fire hydrant between your parked car and the bank, why are you still "parked in front of the bank"? (In fact, why are you parked in front of a fire hydrant in the first place? That's a sure way to get a fine!)

Answer (score 5):

When one thing is *across* something from the other, especially a dividing line or space (like a road), we use **opposite to**. For example, the bank is across the street from the mall, so it is opposite to the mall.

If the bank and the bench aren't separated by anything but (for example) lawn, then the bench is **in front of** the bank.

I cannot reply to Luke Sawczak's comment, but [Merriam Webster definition 1 a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opposite) an example of this definition in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

> **in front of**

has more the meaning

> **directly opposite to**

that two things are

> **facing each other**

whereas

> opposite

means on "*opposing sides*"

[image]

> The ministers sit **opposite** each other, some are **directly in front of** others. The *Speaker's Bench is **in front* of everyone.

In this example

[image]

Foot Locker and McDonald's are **opposite** each other and there is a subway entrance **in front of** Foot Locker and another **in front of** McDonald's, or more specifically **directly in front of**. The bus is also **in front of** McDonald's and **opposite** Foot Locker.  The street lamps are **in front of** the buildings.